# Is there some literature to understand finite state ISI channel?

Tags: reference-request, information-theory, interference

I am trying to understand channels with memory, where the state of the channel gives the past input information. I want to delve further into capacity for channels with ISI. I came across a presentation given [here](http://pfister.ee.duke.edu/talks/globecom01.pdf), on the $5^{th}$ page of it I found a Markov and dicode representation like this:
[image].

I want to know if there is some primarily literature that concerns itself with understanding this channel, and specifically how to read this binary channel with ISI, and also with dicode channels. Any help will be great

Comment: I would start with Proakis, "Digital Communications". It devotes one chapter to ISI channels, and it's a classic reference.

Answer (score 1):

you can also start by "signal processing for everyone" for Gilbert Strang, it's brief and easy to understand. Then you can go with Proakis, "Digital Communications". also there are very good online videos on youtube for India teachers, you are follow them.

Comment: I want to know about any literature that gives me some hints to understand the standard trellis mentioned/drawn above not just ISI.